# WebService sync with plist and plist sync WebService

Tags: objective-c, web-services, synchronization, plist

I want to sync only strings and numbers, then ask:
What is the best and safest way to synchronize a plist with the webservice?
When the user is offline, using the app, synchronize webservice so finding a network, or open the app? With confidence, knowing that the plist file has been tampered with or not.
Anyone done this? It's a right way to do this?

If it was not clear, please advise me to give more details.

Comment: You can work with an encrypted version of the plist locally. But just remember you can never be 100% sure that no one has tampered with the file.

Comment: Hi @Joe, i whant populate a plist to "backup" and sync all info inside it to a webservice. When network is activate, webservice will sync and webservice and plist must has all info synced. i dont whant to upload plist as a file, only info inside, ok!

Comment: Thats fine but if your goal is to prevent the plist from being tampered with while the user is offline it should be stored on disk encrypted. When you decrypt the file in memory you will then send the data to the server.

Comment: hummm ok! i got it. But this is the best way to do that ? Thanks again!

Comment: Here is some discussion on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465271/securing-xml-plists-in-cocoa-objective-c, Also see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694885/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-and-delete-a-plist-file

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation!